# How do I fix this "Name is not Defined"?

Tags: python

Just wondering, how can I fix this? I can't get it to work no matter what I do. Since I've started using Python my main problem is calling variables, exactly how do I do it? For example in this case how do I fix it, or in another code how would I call a variable from one section to another?

I get a

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Test.py", line
>   12, in 
>   while guess != number: NameError: name 'guess' is not defined

Error

As a side note, why does using `Global X = Global X + 1` not work?

```
import random

def main():
 guessesTaken = 0
 guess = 0
 number = random.randint (1, 1000)
 print('Guess a number from 1 to 1000. debug=',number,)
 guess = float(input('  '))
 Hot = number + 10
 Cold = number - 10

while guess != number:

 guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1   
 if guess > number:
  print('Too High!')

 elif guess < number:
  print('Your guess is too low.')

 elif guess < Hot > number:
  print('Your guess Hot!')

 elif guess < Cold > number:
  print('Your guess is Cold!.')

 else:
  print('Error')

while guess == number:
  print('You got it!, you guessed the number in' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

main()
```

Comment: Is that the real indentation of the file?

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.3 and Not really, the page just asked me to add 4 indentations to post it, but that isn't the problem. I get a Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TEST.py", line 12, in <module>
    while guess != number:
NameError: name 'guess' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Do you realize that indentation means ALOT in python? If you don't post the exact code you have with the exact indentation it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your specific issue of `NameError: name 'guess' is not defined` is because `guess` is defined in your `main` function, but the while loop that it is failing on is outside of that function.

Your indention is entirely wrong for this application.

If you want your `while guess != number:` to work, you need to make it part of `main`

```
def main():
    guessesTaken = 0
    guess = 0
    number = random.randint (1, 1000)
    print('Guess a number from 1 to 1000. debug=',number,)
    guess = float(input('  '))
    Hot = number + 10
    Cold = number - 10

    while guess != number:
        ...
```

---

You have other indention problems all over too. Within `main` your lines are indented 5 spaces (not the [PEP8 prescribed 4 spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008#id12)).

Your while loop isn't going to do what you are hoping. If a user doesn't get the answer right on the first try, it is going to hit your `while guess != number:` and loop forever. To resolve this, your input should occur within the loop as well. The second while loop  `while guess == number:` would hit the same infinite loop. Why does this need to print repeatedly? It could work just fine as an `if`

Answer (score 1):

In python, the indentation determines the code block (and thus scope).

So, in your code, when you unindent for your while loops:

```
def main():
   guessesTaken = 0
   guess = 0
   number = random.randint (1, 1000)
   print('Guess a number from 1 to 1000. debug=',number,)
   guess = float(input('  '))
   Hot = number + 10
   Cold = number - 10

while guess != number:   # The unindent here 
   guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
   ...
```

The interpreter treats `Cold = number - 10` as the end of main().  So, your loop is not a part of main() and can't access variables that are local to main (such as guess).

My guess is your intention was to have both while loops part of main.  So they should be indented to match:

```
import random
def main():
     guessesTaken = 0
     guess = 0
     number = random.randint (1, 1000)
     print('Guess a number from 1 to 1000. debug=',number,)
     guess = float(input('  '))
     Hot = number + 10
     Cold = number - 10

     while guess != number:
         guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
         if guess > number:
             print('Too High!')
         elif guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.')
         elif guess < Hot > number:
            print('Your guess Hot!')
         elif guess < Cold > number:
            print('Your guess is Cold!.')
         else:
            print('Error')

     while guess == number:
         print('You got it!, you guessed the number in' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

main()
```

Although, as is your code has other issues; it gives me an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the indentation of your code, I am guessing that the only problem here is that you have not indented the while loop.

Indentation in python is very important. Here is the corrected code :

```
import random


def main():
     guessesTaken = 0
     guess = 0
     number = random.randint (1, 1000)
     print('Guess a number from 1 to 1000. debug=',number,)
     guess = float(input('  '))
     Hot = number + 10
     Cold = number - 10

     while guess != number:

         guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

         if guess > number:
             print('Too High!')


         elif guess < number:
             print('Your guess is too low.')


         elif guess < Hot > number:
            print('Your guess Hot!')


         elif guess < Cold > number:
            print('Your guess is Cold!.')

         else:
            print('Error')
```

What seems to be happening with your current code is that the while loop gets called even before your main() function is called. Therefore 'guess' and 'number' both do not exist in that context.